# How to get last browsed file list shown under dropdown menu of "File name" in file browse window?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, registry

Is it possible to retrieve the file list shown under drop down of file name?
May be some batch command or registry location, so that can be called by any programming language.
[image: Image shows file name drop down menu of last accessed/browsed files]

Comment: That's part of the native dialog, so I don't really know. Maybe…?

Comment: Yes, though tk_getOpenFile window have same listing.

Comment: On Windows, that uses the same native dialog system. By specification and design.